# Remember array after the popup has closed in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, background, popup

I have some programming knowledge, however I didn't work extensively in Javascript or dealt with Chrome extensions before. I'm looking to build a Chrome extension that opens up the selected links in new tabs (that is the initial goal I want to achieve, as my final goal is to open the links in frames of the same tab - if possible -, in order to save the images from those links, similar to what the Save Images extension for Firefox is doing).

I have a problem though: the selected links from my popup are not being "remembered" in order to open them using a delay, after the popup window is closed (due to opening the new tabs). I guess this is related to not making a background script to perform the operation, instead of popup.js? Perhaps some message passing between those two Javascipt files? Just guessing here...

Here is my code so far:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Get links",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get links from a page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "downloads", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="width:400px;">
    <form id="linksform">
      <p>
        <label for="matchregex" style="margin-left: 7px;">RegEx Match: </label>
        <input id="regextext" type="text" style="width:90px;" name="matchregex" value="" />
        <input id="togglematches" type="button" value="Toggle Matches" />
        <input id="openselected" type="button" value="Open Selected" />
      </p>
      <table id='links'>
        <th></th>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
var alllinks = [];
var visiblelinks = [];
var selectedlinks = [];
var delay = 1000;

// Display all visible links.

function showlinks()
  {
  var togglematchesbutton = document.getElementById('togglematches');
  var openselectedbutton = document.getElementById('openselected');
  var linkstable = document.getElementById('links');
  while (linkstable.children.length > 1)
    {
    linkstable.removeChild(linkstable.children[linkstable.children.length - 1])
    }
  for (var i = 0; i < visiblelinks.length; ++i)
    {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var col0 = document.createElement('td');
    var col1 = document.createElement('td');
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.id = 'check' + i;
    checkbox.checked = false;
    checkbox.value = visiblelinks[i];
    col0.appendChild(checkbox);
    col1.innerText = visiblelinks[i];
    col1.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    col1.onclick = function()
      {
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
      }
    row.appendChild(col0);
    row.appendChild(col1);
    linkstable.appendChild(row);
    }
  togglematchesbutton.onclick = function()
    {
    var regex = new RegExp(document.getElementById("regextext").value);
    var getinputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, max = getinputs.length; i < max; i++)
      {
      if ((getinputs[i].type === 'checkbox') &&  (regex.test(getinputs[i].value))) getinputs[i].checked = !getinputs[i].checked;
      }
    }
  openselectedbutton.onclick = function()
    {
    var getinputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, max = getinputs.length; i < max; i++)
      {
      if ((getinputs[i].type === 'checkbox') && (getinputs[i].checked))
        {
        selectedlinks.push(getinputs[i].value);
        }
      }
    for (var i = 0, max = selectedlinks.length; i < max; i++)
      {
      window.setTimeout(function() {chrome.tabs.create({url: selectedlinks[i]});}, delay);
      //chrome.tabs.create({url: selectedlinks[i]});
      }
    }
  }

// Add links to alllinks and visiblelinks, sort and show them. Sendlinks.js is
// injected into all frames of the active tab, so this listener may be called
// multiple times.

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener
  (
  function(links)
    {
    for (var index in links)
      {
      alllinks.push(links[index]);
      }
    alllinks.sort();
    visiblelinks = alllinks;
    //console.log(links);
    showlinks();
    }
  );

// Set up event handlers and inject sendlinks.js into all frames in the active
// tab.

window.onload = function()
  {
  chrome.windows.getCurrent
    (
    function (currentWindow)
      {
      chrome.tabs.query
        (
        {active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id},
        function(activeTabs)
          {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTabs[0].id, {file: 'sendlinks.js', allFrames: true});
          }
        );
      }
    );
  };
```

**sendlinks.js**

```
// Send back to the popup a sorted deduped list of valid link URLs on this page.
// The popup injects this script into all frames in the active tab.
console.log("Injected");

var links = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
console.log(links);
links = links.map
  (
    function(element)
    {
    // Return an anchor's href attribute, stripping any URL fragment (hash '#').
    // If the html specifies a relative path, chrome converts it to an absolute
    // URL.
    var href = element.href;
    var hashIndex = href.indexOf('#');
    if (hashIndex >= 0)
      {
      href = href.substr(0, hashIndex);
      }
    return href;
    }
  );

links.sort();

// Remove duplicates and invalid URLs.
var kBadPrefix = 'javascript';
for (var i = 0; i < links.length;)
  {
  if (((i > 0) && (links[i] == links[i - 1])) || (links[i] == '') || (kBadPrefix == links[i].toLowerCase().substr(0, kBadPrefix.length)))
    {
    links.splice(i, 1);
    }
  else
    {
    ++i;
    }
  }
console.log(links);

chrome.extension.sendMessage(links);
```

*Note: The most part of this code is taken from somewhere else, and has been modified to suit to my needs.*

The main issue is in this code snippet from popup.js:

```
for (var i = 0, max = selectedlinks.length; i < max; i++)
  {
  window.setTimeout(function() {chrome.tabs.create({url: selectedlinks[i]});}, delay);
  //chrome.tabs.create({url: selectedlinks[i]});
  }
```

If I comment the setTimeout line and uncomment the following line, it works (e.g. the extension opens the tabs successfully), but it doesn't use a delay between opening successive tabs - which is required for avoiding 'Too many requests' error on some sites. If I let this as it is, it opens the number of tabs that it is supposed to open (using the specified delay), but the urls of those tabs don't match the selected values (basically, they're blank). What I want is the latter to happen, but opening the selected links instead of blank tabs.

Could you please point where my mistake is, and suggest the code modifications to make this work? If doable, by keeping the existing code as close as possible to the posted version (aka perfoming only minor modifications to the source). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved the issue. It turns out that, for some reason, Chrome didn't remember the ***i*** variable inside the `for` loop (maybe because of `settimeout()` working asynchronously compared to the `for` loop, due to the delay?), so it couldn't reference the correct array element.

All I had to do was replace the above

```
window.setTimeout(function() {chrome.tabs.create({url: selectedlinks[i]});}, delay);
```

with

```
window.setTimeout(function() {chrome.tabs.create({url: selectedlinks.shift()});}, delay);
```

and it worked flawlessly. Basically, instead of referencing the array element using the ***i*** variable, the updated code is always referencing the first array element, while removing it at the same time, thus "navigating" through the whole array and eliminating the elements for which tabs have been created.